# Group purchases: Obtain the # and IDs of unique users, a certain user has made group purchases with

Tags: postgresql

There's two ways for me to tackle this problem: Postgresql and Python. If you can help me with any of the two, I'd highly appreciate it :)

First, Postgresql:

I have a list of recurring user instances, that lists every group purchase they did with other users. This means that the other users of the same group purchase also appear in the list and are linked with one another via the group purchase id. As a result, both the user id and the group purchase id appear several times.

The list looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------+
| purchase_id | user_id |
+-------------+---------+
| p_01        | u_3     |
| p_01        | u_4     |
| p_01        | u_5     |
| p_02        | u_3     |
| p_02        | u_6     |
| p_03        | u_5     |
| p_03        | u_6     |
+-------------+---------+
```

Users do not necessarily buy with the same purchase partners. Some users might have the same purchase partners all the time, others might never buy with the same users.

My problem is the following:
I'd like to figure out the total number of different purchase partners per user across all his/her purchases and I can't come up with a feasible approach. If possible, I'd also like to list the purchase partners per user.

Second, Python:

Alternatively, I can arrange the data aggregated per purchase, as you can see in the following:

```
+-------------+------------------+
| purchase_id |     user_ids     |
+-------------+------------------+
| p_01        | u_3,u_4,u_5      |
| p_02        | u_3,u_6          |
| p_03        | u_5,u_6          |
+-------------+------------------+
```

The column user_ids would be a python list. 
Is there a way to solve this with Python?

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
+---------+--------------------------+
| user_id | unique purchase-partners |
+---------+--------------------------+
| u_3     | u_4, u_5, u_6            |
| u_4     | u_3, u_5                 |
| u_5     | u_3, u_4, u_6            |
| u_6     | u_3, u_5                 |
+---------+--------------------------+
```

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Something like `select user_id, count(distinct purchase_partner) from ... join ... group by user_id`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, a_horse_with_no_name, I added the table. 

Your idea looks good, but unfortunately, there is no column called purchase partners. The purchase partners can solely be identified via the purchase_ids.

Comment: Then count the purchase_ids

Comment: I need the number of different purchase partners, not the number of purchases. For each I need to scan a different set of purchases and obtain the unique user_ids.



I also have the option to use Python, which I added to the problem description.

Comment: Maybe someone has a suggestion to solve this in Python instead of PostgreSQL? Thanks in advance, I appreciate it!

Comment: So how do you link from the `purchase_id` to the Purchase Partner? Do you have another table that you can join?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure whether I understand. Imho, these two tables contain all the relevant information, right? The purchase partners of a certain `purchase_id` are the `user_id`s of the bespoke `purchase_id`.

Comment: Then it sounds as if `count(distinct purchase_id)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome, if it would be that easy. However, this is simply gonna get me the number of `group purchases`. What I need is a script that scans the set of `group purchases` that each `user` did and derives the names of the purchase partners of each `user`.

Comment: So that brings me back to my last question: how do you get from `purchase_id` (which seems to be the same as the "group purchase"?)  to the "purchase partner"? You should add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including the "purchase groups" and the "purchase partners") explain how they relate to each other, some sample data as `insert into` and the expected result based on that data.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any `create table` statements, because it's a result of lots of previous scripts in Dataiku. 

The link between `purchase_id` to the the purchase partners of each `user_id` is obvious. Have a look at the original post, I added an example of what I would like to obtain. You'll see that all necessary info is in the original tables, no extra links needed.

Comment: Any additional approaches to this issue?